# How to change grid density in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there a way for lowering grid density to about 1cm (independently of zoom)?
I only see option for on/off grid.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the on/off grid option just shows or hides the dotted grid background, which is independent of the "zoom". I think you are referring to the "snap to grid" functionality?

Answer (score 14):

Next to the "Grid" checkbox on the Diagram menu, there's a numerical value. That's the size of the grid, which you can increase and decrease.

Visual:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: you need to click off any elements to see the Diagram panel. :doh:

Answer (score 1):

You can change point density of grid by format panel  https://support.draw.io/display/DFJS/Format+Panel
You can see it only if nothing of your diagram is selected. Note that the screen grid doesn't change, but when you move or resize the object you'll realize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change draw points only at creation or at loading of the diagram; then in panel format you'll see "Diagram" and you can change the point of grid.

Comment: I did not see the option to change "draw points" when creating a new diagram

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snapshot of the Diagram panel.
[image: Diagram Panel: View: Grid]